# SELECT FOR UPDATE returns zero rows

Tags: postgresql, transactions

---

**UPDATE: Problem solved!**

That was a [bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/24622.1474558607%40sss.pgh.pa.us) in PostgreSQL. Tom Lane fixed it in this
[commit](http://git.postgresql.org/pg/commitdiff/96dd77d349424f270d129f8f40e75f762ddcca7d).

---

Why SELECT FOR UPDATE returns 0 rows in scenario below? But if I just execute sql query from second transaction it always returns 1 row.

**TRANSACTION 1:**

```
BEGIN;
-- This query updates t1c1 to its current value, it doesn't change anything
UPDATE t1 SET t1c3 = 'string_value_1' WHERE t1c1 = 123456789;

-- Query returned successfully: one row affected, 51 msec execution time.
```

**TRANSACTION 2:**

```
WITH 
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT t2c2 FROM t2 WHERE t2c1 = 'string_value_2'
    ),

    cte2 AS (
        SELECT * FROM t1
        WHERE 
             t1c1 = 123456789 
            AND t1c2 = (SELECT t2c2 FROM cte1)
        FOR UPDATE
    ) 

SELECT * FROM cte2

-- Waiting
```

**TRANSACTION 1:**

```
COMMIT;

-- Query returned successfully with no result in 41 msec.
```

**TRANSACTION 2:**

```
-- Returned 0 rows
```

**Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (_pk serial, t1c1 integer, t1c2 integer, t1c3 text);
CREATE TABLE t2 (_pk serial, t2c1 text, t2c2 integer);
insert into t1 (t1c1, t1c2, t1c3) values(123456789, 100, 'string_value_1');
insert into t2 (t2c1, t2c2) values('string_value_2', 100);
```

Comment: Cannot you provide a minimal complete example? i.e. include your `create table` statements and some `insert` statements if necessary.

Comment: @redneb :

CREATE TABLE t1 (_pk serial, t1c1 integer, t1c2 integer, t1c3 text);
CREATE TABLE t2 (_pk serial, t2c1 text, t2c2 integer);
insert into t1 (t1c1, t1c2, t1c3) values(123456789, 100, 'string_value_1');
insert into t2 (t2c1, t2c2) values('string_value_2', 100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is a bug in PostgreSQL, and you should report it.

Comment: I was right; Tom Lane fixed it in [this commit](http://git.postgresql.org/pg/commitdiff/96dd77d349424f270d129f8f40e75f762ddcca7d).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!  With `explain verbose analyze`, I get the following query plan:

```
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CTE Scan on cte2  (cost=51.13..51.15 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=4544.488..4544.488 rows=0 loops=1)
   Output: cte2._pk, cte2.t1c1, cte2.t1c2, cte2.t1c3
   CTE cte1
     ->  Seq Scan on public.t2  (cost=0.00..24.50 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: t2.t2c2
           Filter: (t2.t2c1 = 'string_value_2'::text)
   CTE cte2
     ->  LockRows  (cost=0.12..26.63 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=4544.485..4544.485 rows=0 loops=1)
           Output: t1._pk, t1.t1c1, t1.t1c2, t1.t1c3, t1.ctid
           InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
             ->  CTE Scan on cte1  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
                   Output: cte1.t2c2
           ->  Seq Scan on public.t1  (cost=0.00..26.50 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: t1._pk, t1.t1c1, t1.t1c2, t1.t1c3, t1.ctid
                 Filter: ((t1.t1c1 = 123456789) AND (t1.t1c2 = $1))
 Planning time: 0.116 ms
 Execution time: 4544.535 ms
(17 rows)
```

The outer "CTE Scan on cte2" seems to drop the row that was still there during the "LockRows" step.  Postgres is known to re-evaluate `where` clauses after acquiring a lock (see [this example with work queues](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/).)  Perhaps the query plan contains a `where` clause on the invisible `ctid` row identifier, which does change after any `UPDATE` ?

I've asked [this question](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/29BD83DE-482E-409F-A1BB-4C63492CF158%40aule.net) on the [Postgres mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/) to see if other people are able to clarify what's happening here.

Answer (score -1):

FOR UPDATE has no meaning inside CTE. This should work though:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT t2c2 FROM t2 WHERE t2c1 = "string_value_2"
),

cte2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM t1
    WHERE 
         t1c1 = 123456789 
        AND t1c2 = (SELECT t2c2 FROM cte1)
) 

SELECT * FROM cte2  FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html) says that "FOR UPDATE" can be used within WITH query:


If a locking clause is applied to a view or sub-query, it affects all tables used in the view or sub-query. However, these clauses do not apply to WITH queries referenced by the primary query. If you want row locking to occur within a WITH query, specify a locking clause within the WITH query.